# Is there a way to change the tab indent / formatting of the XML when exporting to a string?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, e4x

I have an XML object that I'm exporting to a string like so:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(myString);
trace(xml.toXMLString());
```

This results in something like:

```
<root>
 <item>
  <item>
   <item/>
  </item>
 </item>
</root>
```

However, the indentations are much to short in my opinion especially with a lot of content and it's hard to read. Irregardless of the reasons is there a way to increase the indentations like maybe to use tabs or more tabs instead of spaces? Not sure what it's using (will check). 
I would like it to look closer to this. It looks much cooler too.

```
<root>
    <item>
        <item>
            <item/>
        </item>
    </item>
</root>
```

**UPDATE:**
I found the XML.prettyPrint setting and turned it on (set to true). It didn't work how I expected and indented and spaced out the line height.

Here it is **before**:
[image]

Here it is **after**:
[image]
I'm turning pretty print off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) class has static properties that control the formatting output.

```
XML.prettyIndent = 4;
trace(xml)
```

Also, I'm not sure why they made these settings static, but to avoid tampering with settings that might affect code elsewhere you can read the current settings using `XML.settings()` then restore them after you are done using `XML.setSettings()`.

Comment: Thanks. It increased the indentation. Oddly enough the tab size increases in width the higher the value is.